# newbie question - how to list people who has not email address related to him/her?

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many

Sorry for my newbie question: I would like to list all people even those who has no email address in case of using many-to-many relation with superclass-sublclass inheritance.

Please see SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8f556/8

Postgresql lists only the people who has email...

I tried this query:

```
select people.c_id as "ID", 
    people.c_family_name as "Family Name",
    people.c_last_name as "Last Name",
    email.c_email as "Email"
from
    t_email email,
    t_people people
    left join t_ref_email ref_email on ref_email.c_party = people.c_id
where ref_email.c_party = people.c_id 
  and ref_email.c_email = email.c_id;
```

Result:

```
ID  Family Name Last Name   Email
1000    Test    Joe test_email@email.com
```

Test Bill was not listed because he has no email address...

Comment: you should not mix the ancient implicit joins in the where clause an explicit `JOIN` operators.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your response! Can you correct my query? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases should be short and meaningful

```
select pe.c_id as "ID", 
    pe.c_family_name as "Family Name",
    pe.c_last_name as "Last Name",
    em.c_email as "Email"
    
from
t_people pe
LEFT JOIN t_ref_email re ON re.c_party = pe.c_id
LEFT JOIN t_email em ON em.c_id = re.c_email
```

With the result of

```
ID      Family Name     Last Name   Email
1000    Test            Joe         test_email@email.com
1001    Test             Bill        (null)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)